# Converting json from json_ecode() to a javascript array

Tags: javascript

I am using the `json_encode()` in php to return a json object. How can i convert it to a javascript array?

input:

```
[{"message":"1"},{"message":"2"}]
```

output

```
["1", "2"]
```

Comment: `Object.values(object)` will give you all the values of the object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this way

```js
const data = '[{"message":"1"},{"message":"2"}]'

const result = JSON.parse(data).map(o=>o.message)

console.log( result )
```